# Converting TSE data to STS with TraMineRextras

Tags: type-conversion, sequence, traminer

I have a data set which is formatted like TSE:

[image]

Event is a code of the mode of entry (1 is export, 2 to 5 is partenariat, 6 to 7 is Acq.Mino, 8 is Acq_Majo). Country is not used.

I would like to convert this table to a sequence object, and I understood that the TSE_to_STS function would help me to do so. However it seems that the output is not as I expect.

I ran the code:

```
seq.sts<-TSE_to_STS(seq.tse.data,id = 1, timestamp = 2, event = 3, stm =NULL, tmin = 1935,tmax = 2018, firstState = "None").
```

the output is for company 7:

```
> seq.sts[7,]
```

[image]

My first surprise is that the event happened in year n and are coded in year n+1 (in red in the above output). My second surprise is that in 2013 and in 2015 I lose information about the second entry in Thailand (in yellow in the above output).Third, I don’t understand why the states are added: why do we have in 2012 Acq_Mino.Acq_Majo and not only Acq_Mino?

Answer (score 0):

The TSE_to_STS function is intended to convert time-stamped event sequences into state sequences. This is done by defining the state in which we are after the event occurs. With “stm = NULL”, the state after each event is characterized as the combination of the current state and the event.

Your example is not reproducible because:

1. We do not know the re-labeling you applied to your events coded from 1 to 8, and
2. Seems that you mixed the `timestamp` and `event` arguments in the `TSE_to_STS` example command.

I illustrate below with a reproducible example (based on your example except for the `country` column that we do not use).

```
library(TraMineRextras)
seq.tse.data <- structure(list(
  ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
         4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
         6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L),
  Year = c(2008L, 2010L, 2012L, 2007L, 2009L, 2010L, 2012L,
           2013L, 1996L, 1997L, 1999L, 2003L, 2006L, 2008L, 
           2012L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2003L, 2007L, 2007L,
           2009L, 2009L, 2011L, 2014L, 2016L, 2006L, 2009L, 
           2011L, 2013L, 2013L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L), 
  Event = c(8L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
            3L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
            8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 
            8L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -34L)
  )
seq.tse.data[seq.tse.data$ID==7,]

#    ID Year Event
# 27  7 2006     8
# 28  7 2009     8
# 29  7 2011     7
# 30  7 2013     7
# 31  7 2013     6
# 32  7 2015     7
# 33  7 2015     6
# 34  7 2016     8

seq.sts <- TSE_to_STS(seq.tse.data,
                 id = 1, timestamp = 2, event = 3, 
                 stm =NULL, tmin = 1990, tmax = 2018,
                 firstState = "None")
```

For the id 7, we get:

```
seq.sts[7,which(names(seq.sts)=="a2005"):which(names(seq.sts)=="a2018")]

#   a2005 a2006 a2007 a2008 a2009 a2010 a2011 a2012 a2013 a2014 a2015 a2016 a2017 a2018
# 7  None  None     8     8     8     8     8   8.7   8.7 8.7.6 8.7.6 8.7.6 8.7.6 8.7.6
```

In this example, for `id=7` the first event (`8`) occurs in 2006. Therefore the state is `None` until 2006 and switches to `8` afterwards. In 2011, event `7` occurs. So, the next year (2012) we switch to the state 'events 8 and 7 already occurred', which is denoted as `8.7`. When `7` occurs again in 2013, it does not change the state because `7` already occurred while the occurrence of event 6 leads to the state `8.7.6`. The latter becomes effective the next year, i.e. in 2014.

Different schemes for determining the state resulting after the occurrence of each event can be defined by providing the `stm` matrix to the `TSE_to_STS` function. Use the `seqe2stm` function for defining the `stm` matrix. (Look at the help page of this latter function for more details.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You are right, I made a mistake in the code of the sts function (while copying the code to stackoverflow). I was fine on my PC though.
I also changed the text to explain categories of events.
Thank you very much for your explanations, it's very clear now.

Comment: How this function, TSE_to_STS, handle NA values? I have a similar set of data than Antonin but with NA values in the time variable. The message i got is "Error in prevTime:tt : argument NA / NaN". I guess there are no ways of handling NA with TSE_to_STS, am I right?

Comment: If you do not know when an event happens you cannot do much. With some reasonable assumptions you can perhaps make a guess for its timestamp. Otherwise, you are perhaps best to ignore the event.